# Why do English people call baked potatoes 'jacket potatoes'?

Tags: phrases, british-english, names

Why do English people call baked potatoes 'jacket potatoes'? Is it because they do not peel the potato before cooking it and use 'jacket' to refer to the peel?

Comment: Scottish, Welsh, Irish, Australian, and New Zealand people call them that, too.

Comment: Now then, @Michael, you could have easily found the answer on Google.

Comment: The jacket is not the peel but the skin: the peel is what comes off, but the jacket is left on. As with 'orange peel' the 'peel' is the bits of skin that you have taken *off*.

Comment: FWIW, when I was searching for the answer, one of the top results is so [poorly written as to be confusing](https://historianandrew.medium.com/the-fascinating-history-of-the-baked-potato-c7092b550da5#:~:text=stuffing%20the%20piping%20hot%20%E2%80%9Cjacket%E2%80%9D%20potatoes%20in%20their%20coat%20pockets%20for%20warmth) (it looks like it's giving the origin of the term, but it's not) and none of the other sources actually gave a straight answer as to the origin of the term. (It would be nice if someone could pin down a more exact date for when it first appeared in English.)

Comment: @WeatherVane - not sure what that means. To cook a jacket potato, we take the potato exactly as it came out of the ground, scrub it well, and put it in the oven. After around 45 minutes or so, depending on size, out it comes, and we usually cut it open and put butter, cheese, baked beans, etc on the inside white stuff. Then we eat it. Fussy types leave the peel, skin, or whatever you call it. In out house we eat it.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/peel) says: *especially after it has been removed*. It used to be the skin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One definition for *jacket*, according to [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/jacket):

> the skin of a potato, etc.

Here are some examples:

> Edward, the waiter, bruising the leathery jacket of the potato dexterously in his napkin, tumbles out the hot flour.
> — [All the Year Round](https://books.google.com/books?id=LnI-AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA590&dq=%22jacket+of+the+potato%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjsyvPC16P6AhWeFFkFHZIwC1wQ6AF6BAgDEAM#v=onepage&q=%22jacket%20of%20the%20potato%22&f=false) (1868)

> Potato (cooked in jacket).
> — [Children's Bureau Publication](https://books.google.com/books?id=-YBGAQAAIAAJ&pg=RA3-PA28&dq=%22jacket%20potato%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjniber2KP6AhWfEFkFHUy6DM8QuwV6BAgJEAc#v=onepage&q=%22jacket%22&f=false) (1917)

From there, it's easy to see how it became a "jacket potato", since it's a potato that's baked with its skin (the "jacket") on. I think the expression "jacket potato" was first used in the 20th century.

Comment: When I was growing up in London in the 1950s and 1960s, my parents called them 'potatoes in their jackets'. My mother was especially scornful of people she called 'fussy namby-pambies' who ate the insides and left the skins. This is an attitude I share to this day. I have a feeling that the two-word phrase 'jacket potato' gained popularity as they became something you could buy already cooked in cafés or takeaway outlets, rather than just cook at home. It is shorter on a menu or notice.

Answer (score 0):

Correct. The jacket refers to the intact skin.

"A jacket potato is a large potato that has been baked with its skin on.
[British]" (collinsdictionary.com)

"Jacket potatoes are eaten as main dishes in Britain. Split in half and topped with fillings such as beans, tuna, and chili, the souped-up spuds are known as "jacket potatoes," a reference to the intact potato skin." (insider.com)

Sources:

- https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/jacket-potato
- https://www.insider.com/foods-different-names-around-the-world-2018-10#a-jacket-potato-in-the-uk-is-a-baked-potato-in-america-12

Comment: Not my downvote but answers should be self-contained because over time  links rot or websites get closed, so could you copy and paste the most relevant parts, please?